# Loop through HTML elements string and insert with jquery

Tags: jquery, pjax

I am using rails and jquery.  On button hit i'm returning results from a partial.

```
$(".blog-posts ul").append("<%= j render('blog/posts')%>").hide().fadeIn(400);
```

The results from that are:

```
"<li class=\"post item\"><div class=\"overlay\"><h5><a href=\"/blog/post-slug\">Post Title<\/a><\/h5><\/div><\/li>
 <li class=\"post item\"><div class=\"overlay\"><h5><a href=\"/blog/post-slug\">Post Title<\/a><\/h5><\/div><\/li>
 <li class=\"post item\"><div class=\"overlay\"><h5><a href=\"/blog/post-slug\">Post Title<\/a><\/h5><\/div><\/li>"
```

As you can see it returns a string but what I am trying to do is grab every li element as html and append it to a ul but can't seem to get it working.

I've tried a multitude of things, similar to this

```
 $('li', $("<%= j render('blog/posts')%>")).each(function(i) {
     $(this).appendTo('.blog-posts ul');
 });
```

But it doesn't append them.  I'm trying to append each li with a delay.

I've even tried:

```
 $('li', $("<%= j render('blog/posts')%>")).each(function(i) {
   $(this).delay((i++) * 500).appendTo('.blog-posts ul').fadeTo(1000, 1);
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the top level of the html string is `<li>` you can use `filter()` to get each or wrap the new `<li>` 's in a `<ul>` to access them using `find()` or `children()`

```
var $newList=$("<ul>").html("<%= j render('blog/posts')%>"),   
     delay=500,
     $list=$('.blog-posts ul');

$newList.children().each(function(i, elem){      
  setTimeout(function(){
      $list.append(elem);
   }, delay*i);
});
```

Comment: Seems like using new ul and children is easiest, not sure about performance issues though. Awesome! Thanks a lot, works great just need to modify my transitions and append.